# Create an annualized time based trigger

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a trigger that will run Jan 2 of every year.

The timedrive trigger only goes up to monthly occurrence, which will not work, so then I thought of adding it via GAS...I found this in my search:

```
 var triggerDay = new Date(2012, 11, 1);
 ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
   .timeBased()
   .at(triggerDay)
   .create();
```

at -- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder

My thought was to alter like so:

```
     var d =  new Date(new Date());
     var yr = d.getFullYear();
     var triggerDay = new Date(yr, 1, 2);
     ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
       .timeBased()
       .at(triggerDay)
       .create();
```

But I don't think this will work as it will create the trigger once with the current year.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  What if I created a function set to a daily trigger that would in turn create trigger script...would this work?

Answer (score 0):

Create a trigger that runs daily, and does something if it's the correct date, and does nothing if it's the wrong date.

```
function myTrigger() {
  //var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
  //You can omit any of the last 4 parameters
  var dateToCheck = new Date(2016, 1, 2);
  var todaysDate = new Date();

  if (todaysDate === dateToCheck) {
    //Do something
    .... run your code here
  };
};
```

Comment: Ok going with your idea I create a install a trigger for the function "myTrigger()" that is set to run daily...every day this trigger runs and checks to see if the current date (or perhaps it would be better if it were the next days date is Jan 1 of the next year.  If it is then the function creates a new trigger that will run only on that date?  I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: No need to create a second trigger.  Just run whatever code you need to run if the condition is met.